# C++ Program Crashing on execution

Tags: c++, parsing

I am using Code Blocks and am doing a small compilers which is an assignment.

At the moment I'm doing the Parser.

So In this problem I am using 3 Files: `Lexer.h` `Token.h` `Parser.h`

My Problem is this:

I have a `Vector` which is full of `tokens` example int real, string all of these will but put into the parser (which I am also designing) to see whether it fits the set of EBNF I have.

The problem is here.

The Vector is found in `Lexer.h`.
Now, in `Parser.h` I make user of a Method called `NextToken()` which is found in Lexer.h. The job of this method is to get the next Token found in the Vector and return it so I can compare it to see whether it is good or not.

Now when I try to get some piece of information using a Getter set in Token.h for e.g. `tk -> getType()`, the program looks like it's in a loop and in around 1 second, it Crashes.

Any idea why it is crashing?

this is the coding: [Partial Coding]

### Lexer.h

---

```
vector<Token> tokensUsed; // Vector containing the Tokens
vector<Token>::iterator it;  // Iterator 
Token* itrToken; 

 Token* nextToken()
            {
                if (it!= tokensUsed.end())
                {
                    // we Assigned what is found in the iterator it (of the vector)
                    // so we get the data found in that pointer
                    itrToken = &*this->it;
                    //Move Iterator forward
                    it ++;
                    return itrToken;
                }
            }
```

### Token.h

---

```
Token ()
{

}


Token (int type, string sBuffer, int rRow, int cCol)
{
    this->tType = type;
    this->strBuffer = sBuffer;
    this->row = rRow;
    this->col = cCol;
}

// Since it points to a pointer in the memory, this will get the element FROM the memory
// by passing the Pointer Token from the lexer.h
Token (Token* getT)
{
    this-> tType = getT -> tType;
    this->strBuffer = getT -> strBuffer;
    this->row = getT -> row;
    this->col = getT -> col;
}


//Getters
//Will return the corresponding data according to the function of that particular token

//Return the type [enum] of the token
int getType ()
{
    return this->tType;
}

//return the string contents
string getBuffer()
{
    return this->strBuffer;
}

//return row
int getRow()
{
    return row;
}

//return col
int getCol ()
{
    return col;
}
```

### Parser.h

---

Will give you just the method that is crashing

```
    void TypeNode()
    {

        //Create New Token
        Token* tk = nextToken();
        valueType = tk -> getType();
        valueString = tk -> getBuffer();

        //Create Node
        cout << "Type Node:  " << valueType << "  " << valueString << endl;
        //ASTNode* tNode = new ASTNode(valueType, valueString);

    }
```

ASTNODE is for now commented as I am testing with cout for now

EDIT: I edited the Code Christian Rapp Told me: but whenever I try to execute this Happens:

[image: Error]

Comment: return tk; what is this? where is tk defined?

Comment: And where is `it` initialized? is it really global?

Comment: I don't see where that global "vector<Token>::iterator it" in "Lexer.h" is being initialized. Are you certain it's pointing to somewhere within the tokenUsed vector?

Comment: it is set as private, but I am declaring it this way: `vector<Token>::iterator it;`
At the end of the Lexer.h I have  `it = tokensUsed.begin();`

Comment: It is at the end of the whole lexer as it is checking each character so it is rather long.
@ChristianRapp, `tk` is begin declared at the top of the lexer

Comment: I still don't understand you pass the value to itrToken but return a variable called tk. have you tried a debugger?

Comment: vector<T>::begin() returns an iterator to the first element of the vector. Are you by any chance calling it on an empty vector? If so, it will crash when dereferenced.

Comment: @ChristianRapp... Big Mistake from My Part... I Changed it to itrToken, but now random data and a crash happened, Editing post

Comment: @Igvidal , no, I tried testing that there are elements inside it, it worked, just a simple `cout << "test" << endl` . Now am trying to get the proper data

Comment: @Igvidal, I tried testing it from within Lexer.h itself, and IT WORKS, as in The Getter works. BUT from within Parser.h it Crashes

Comment: Without a [minimal complete example](http://www.sscce.org), we have little chance of solving this.

Comment: Obviously a segmentation fault or unallocated memory access is happening in the program. This is an error you better find yourself.

Comment: What do you mean by unallocated memory access?

Comment: @Beta, the only thing I can offer you is giving you my code via PasteBin

Comment: That means accessing memory you should not access. That often results in random characters in the output when reading strings (because it will just read until 0 is encountered). And it also quite often cases crashes.

Comment: @DodoSerebro don't pastebin; post your code on this thread, and remove all code that you can remove and still have the problem happen. You will have to make some effort. See the link Beta posted.

Comment: I Tried running a TEST, to check how many elements I have in the vector. When it is still inside the `getNextToken() ` (not shown here) method, it shows 3.. when I try to access from Parser.h... it goes to buffer overflow like 32000000+

Comment: 3200000+ seems like a trash random number from memory. Very likely you are accessing wrong parts of memory.

Answer (score 0):

The `nextToken` function is badly broken.

1. You are copying the token, but your `Token` class has no copy constructor.
2. You have no return value if the `if` returns false.
3. You are setting `itrToken` (a global) but returning `itr` (an undefined local).

The lack of copy constructor is probably the biggest problem causing your crash on what seems to be the second token.

Comment: I Tried running a TEST, to check how many elements I have in the vector. When it is still inside the `getNextToken() ` (not shown here) method, it shows 3.. when I try to access from Parser.h... it goes to buffer overflow like 32000000+

Comment: Did you understand a word of what I wrote? Read about copy constructors and you may see why.

Comment: that itr was a mistake from my part, in my program it is itrToken, a typo sorry... you said that I have no copy constructor. In what way? I already have 2 constructors in `Token.h`